# How to cut a string

Tags: c#

I have a strings like
"/LM/W3SVC/1216172363/root/175_Jahre_STAEDTLER_Faszination_Schreiben"

And I need only "175_Jahre_STAEDTLER_Faszination_Schreiben" where "root" is separator. How can I do this?

Comment: +1 for title, it reminds me of how to correctly syntax highlight a lion

Comment: How long is the piece of string?

Comment: psst...don't forget to mark the answer that worked for you.  And if no answer worked, feel free to edit your question.

Comment: Juri: are you by any chance trying to parse XML?  If so, I'll post an XPath example for you.

Comment: Just a quick check: did none of these answers work for you?  You can always edit the question if necessary.  And if an answer worked, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 20):

`"/LM/W3SVC/1216172363/root/175_Jahre_STAEDTLER_Faszination_Schreiben".Split("/root/")[1]` should give you "175_Jahre_STAEDTLER_Faszination_Schreiben"

Comment: Of course, you should probably assign it to a variable and check that it was able to correctly split the string, to avoid exceptions for badly formed strings.

Answer (score 4):

Another method:

```
String newstring = file_path.Substring(file_path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the System.IO.Path methods - not quite files and folders but with the / delimiter it just might work!

Comment: This seems like it could be prone to some ugly side effects.

Comment: @Mike - yeah, you might be right. I like the .split answers better.

Comment: Yes, due to assumptions about what constitutes a valid separator.  Best to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to extract a part of a string based on an overall pattern, regular expressions *can* be a good alternative in some situations.

```
string s = "/LM/W3SVC/1216172363/root/175_Jahre_STAEDTLER_Faszination_Schreiben";
Regex re = new Regex(@"/root/(?<goodPart>\w+)$");
Match m = re.Match(s);
if (m.Success) {
    return m.Groups["goodPart"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Regex is definitely a good solution for more complicated problems (and I have no idea how complicated the OP's problem actually is)...you just have to take into account the small performance hit.  Regex has its place, but if a simple Split or Substring will do the trick, using regular expressions can actually be detrimental.  (I have nothing against regexes; I use them all the time!  Just imparting helpful comments :)

Comment: @NickAldwin, I agree, just presenting an alternative for completeness. I edited my answer to make that a little clearer, I hope.

Comment: Yep, I understand that and I think it's important to have the alternatives visible (hence my upvote :).  I was just clarifying the Regex vs Split point.  Thanks for posting (and editing for clarity)!

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "/LM/W3SVC/1216172363/root/175_Jahre_STAEDTLER_Faszination_Schreiben";
string separator = "root";
string slash = "/";
int idx = s.IndexOf(separator);
string result = s.SubString(idx + separator.Length + slash.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to separate the string with "root" as the separator.  Then use the second element of the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "/LM/W3SVC/1216172363/root/175_Jahre_STAEDTLER_Faszination_Schreiben";
int li = s.LastIndexOf("root/");
s = s.Substring(li + 5, s.Length - 1 - (li + 4));
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Comment: He did mention he wanted to split on "root", not necessarily on an arbitrary slash...but this is good for general splitting.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find a relative path based on a base path (which it sounds like what the problem you are trying to solve is, or at least a generalization of your problem) you can use the System.Uri class.  It does have it's limitations, however.  The cleanest and most correct way to find a relative path is to use DirectoryInfo.  With DirectoryInfo you can "walk" the directory tree (backwards or forwards) and build a hierarchy based on that.  Then just do a little set manipulation to filter out duplicates and what you have left is your relative path.  There are some details, like adding ellipses in the correct place, etc..., but DirectoryInfo is a good place to start in order to parse paths based on the current OS platform.

FYI - I just finished writing a component here at work to do just that so it's fairly fresh in my mind.